# Regexp vs Include performance comparison in Elasticsearch

Tags: regex, elasticsearch

I work on a project and I need to aggregate the results based on "created" and "labels" field.
I created following queries that both give the result as I expected. But I want to learn that which query runs more fast?

My first query:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "HEATMAP": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "created",
        "interval": "day"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "BEHAVIOUR_CHANGE": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "labels",
            "include": "behavior-change"
          }
        },
        "FIRST_OCCURRENCE": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "labels",
            "include": "first-occurrence"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My second query:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "HEATMAP": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "created",
        "interval": "day"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "BEHAVIOUR_CHANGE": {
          "filter": {
            "regexp": {
              "labels": "behavior-change"
            }
          }
        },
        "FIRST_OCCURRENCE": {
          "filter": {
            "regexp": {
              "labels": "first-occurrence"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the mapping of `labels` field? Provide a sample document for `labels`? What values can it include? Can it have a list of values?

Comment: I am really sorry to forget putting more details for my question. Labels field is a kind of string array

Here is the mapping of labels
"labels": {
            "type": "keyword"
          }

Answer (score 1):

Since that field is a `keyword` and you don't need anything special when it comes to a regular expression (only a perfect match), I would do it like the following. You'd note also that I added a `terms` filter to the `query` part to try and narrow down the results before being put through the aggregations (theoretically, for the aggregations to have less work to do). Also, I don't see a reason to use `regexp` here, thus I used the `terms` aggregations. If you are really interested in the performance comparison, I'd suggest setting up a load test with many more documents and terms in that field and perform some tests. Elastic has its own benchmarking tool that you could use for this: [Rally](https://www.elastic.co/blog/announcing-rally-benchmarking-for-elasticsearch).

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "terms": {
      "labels": [
        "behavior-change",
        "first-occurrence"
      ]
    }
  }, 
  "aggs": {
    "HEATMAP": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "created",
        "interval": "day"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "BEHAVIOUR_CHANGE": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "labels",
            "include": "behavior-change"
          }
        },
        "FIRST_OCCURRENCE": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "labels",
            "include": "first-occurrence"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```